# Method and array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling to solve a mistake in one method. It's an assignment and I'll try to explain it (it's a little bit long)

**First**

I have a method `stepMaxDiff(int[] array)` that returns the index of the maximum absolute difference between elements in one array. For example:

```
Array = [7, 19, 5, 10, 16, 8, 1, 19, 6, 13] 
Index = [0, 01, 2, 03, 04, 5, 6, 07, 8, 09]
```

In this array, the biggest absolute difference is 18 (= 1-19) and it happens in index number 6. This method is working properly in my code.

**Second**

I have a method `select(int[][] arrays)` that needs simply to receive a matrix `(int[][])` as argument and calculates the difference between the number found by `stepMaxDiff` and the length of each line in the matrix (the length of the `array` (row). After that, it prints the line with smaller distance. It's quite simple and I'll give an example:

```
          [17, 11, 02]
 Matrix = [19, 02, 18, 12]
          [14, 02]
```

In this matrix the `select` method needs to return a message saying that line 3 is the select one.
It happens because line 3 is where the biggest absolute difference (found by `stepMaxDiff`) happens closer to the last element of the array. The difference happens in index 0 (=14-2) and line 3 has just 2 elements (index 0 and 1).

**Third**

Finally my code, where I'm getting crazy to find my mistake

```
    int stock = 1000000; // Absurd value to force the variable difference to be smaller than stock when the first iteration 
    int difIndex = 0; // Index where the biggest difference happens
    int difference = 0; // Calculates the difference between stepMaxDiff and matrix.length
    int line; // Number of the line in matrix

    for (line = 0; line < matrix.length; ++line) { // loop runs all over the lines of the matrix

         Math.abs(difference = stepMaxDiff(matrix[line]) - matrix.length);

         if (difference <= stock) { // If difference is smaller than stock it stores the value of difference
            stock = difference;
            difIndex = line; // Stores the line with the smallest difference
         }

    }

  System.out.print("the line select is " + difIndex);
```

With this matrix as argument:

```
[04, 01, 09, 16, 19, 06, 06, 06, 08, 18]
[15, 12, 18, 06]
[01, 15]
[01, 16, 03, 17, 14, 06]
```

My code returns line 3 but the correct one is line 1. Maybe my `for` it's not looping correctly on the lines of the matrix but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: In your first part, after`stepMaxDiff`, what is that second array labeled "Index" represent?

Comment: It represents just the index of the numbers in the array. I was trying to better explain what `stepMaxDiff`returns

Comment: I'd put those offset into a comment, it's pretty confusing adding a second array.  Also, in the second part, what is "length of each line in the matrix?"  Do you mean the length of the array (row)?  The number of characters read?  Something else?

Comment: I mean the length of the array. I'll re-read my post and try to be less confusing (my native language it's not English...)

Comment: Why did you subtract this: 'matrix.length - 1' instead of the length of the line? matrix[line].length?. Because you said: "the difference between the number found by stepMaxDiff and the length of each line in the matrix"

Comment: Should the difference line be `difference = Math.abs( matrix[line] - matric.length );`?

Comment: No. It is `Math.abs(difference = stepMaxDiff(matrix[line]) - matrix.length)`; I need to call `stepMaxDiff`

Comment: @Rods2292 Maybe that line works (no compiler warning or error?), but it looks weird... this makes more sense: `difference = Math.abs(stepMaxDiff(matrix[line]) - matrix.length);`